# Normalization VS Denormalization In Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I thought alot before i post this question here,I am not sure if its proper place to ask this type of question BUT i am sure i can get best guidance.

I have two types of data Eg, Rentals & Sales.Now which one is best practice?

1- Create two tables , rentals & sales.
2- Create One table & keep type 1 for rentals & 2 for sales.

Conditions:

- I am using MySql
- I have too much data lets say 1B sales & 1B rentals

Question:

Which one in above cases is good for me & Why?

**UPDATED:** Both categories have almost the same columns(more than 96%).And users have to see either one or two BUT there are cases that users can see both at once also.More ever other related information like leads & deals are also same for both.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would ask, What percentage of columns do the two categories have in common, and, What percentage of *processing* do the two categories have in common?

Comment: Sir,96% columns are same in both types and same for processing.Updated my question

Comment: In that case I would go with a single table and possibly try to rationalize the few columns that don't match.

Comment: If you have such large number of records, then even if you go for a single table approach, I would suggest you to use partitioning.

Comment: Should i define its Primery key(auto inc.) as BIGINT or  INT?